# Storing variable number of items in a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql, razor

I am using ASP.NET and Razor to create a calendar application similar to Google calendar and was hoping to get some feedback on my design thus far. My idea is to have 2 tables, one normal table for users, and another for a table of events which will store the users id and the time of the event, event ID, name of the event, and duration of the event.

I plan to write some code that will display a calendar on screen and allow the user to select multiple times so as to mark them as busy and give them a name. When this is done, the user submits the information and it is inserted into the database.

What is the best way to go about tackling this calendar construct? I can't really think of a simple way. I am guessing I can create a nice looking calendar using HTML and CSS, and perhaps JS to allow the drag and drop functionality? I suppose when the user selects a time, an object would be created with a start time and default duration, then when they drag it the duration changes. I am confused by how you would do this however, pulling objects out of thin air. How does Google Calendar do this?

And then how do you store all of the created objects in the database? I am guessing that Razor has a foreach construct and that I could just iterate over all objects created and insert them into the database one-by-one?

Also, how could I clean up the database, garbage collecting events that have already transpired while keeping events that are constant ie daily/weekly?

Apologies if the question is vague, if it is too vague then please press me on details I can be more clear on rather than close this. Thank you.

Comment: This might be a better fit for programmers.stackexchange.com. SO is more for questions regarding actual programming questions. If you're still in the design phase of your project then your question probably doesn't belong here.

Comment: It is mostly a programming specific question though! I may not have phrased it correctly, I am sorry. What I am wondering is how to create a drag and drop interface using ASP.NET and saving the valuescreated via dragging and dropping in a database!

Comment: Have you *tried* to implement it yourself? Can you show the code you've tried?

Comment: Some examples of this (even if they are not exactly what I am looking for!) would be really invaluable! I'd love to learn from other peoples code it is difficult to find relevant information, however :-)

Comment: I have a basic shell set up, with a basic form where users are allowed to input information which is stored in a database - I learnt this from the tutorials on http://www.asp.net, however I have no idea how to even begin this without some guidance (hence the lack of code here, and my asking for examples!). Once I get some idea, rest assured I will have code up here, but at the moment it would only serve as a confusion!

Comment: You have a lot of questions here, several of which could easily be their own SO question. Which one are you expecting an answer to here?

Answer (score 0):

1. **What is the best way to go about tackling this calendar construct?**
   If you are wondering about data structure here, whatever you do, do it in that way that it makes it compatible with standard [iCalendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) standard
2. **I can't really think of a simple way.** 
   Calendars are quite complex applications, there is no simple way. (events, sharing events, tentative, attendants, reminders...)
3. **I am guessing I can create a nice looking calendar using HTML and CSS, and perhaps JS to allow the drag and drop functionality?**
   Yes.
4. **I suppose when the user selects a time, an object would be created with a start time and default duration, then when they drag it the duration changes. I am confused by how you would do this however, pulling objects out of thin air. How does Google Calendar do this?**
   You can find some existing jquery plugins for this (try with [this](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) for start, or take a look at [this](http://www.queness.com/post/656/10-beautiful-jquery-and-mootool-calendar-plugins) list).
5. **And then how do you store all of the created objects in the database? I am guessing that Razor has a foreach construct and that I could just iterate over all objects created and insert them into the database one-by-one?**
   Check out these jquery plugins and see how do they communicate with the server side. You will end up making ajax requests and then making database queries in the database. Razor has nothing to do with database...also Razor has nothing to do with client side interaction, it just renders page and everything else is on the js side.
6. **Also, how could I clean up the database, garbage collecting events that have already transpired while keeping events that are constant ie daily/weekly?**
   I would't delete anything from database...don't see a reason for that. Just grab all you have and fill in the calendar. User will always look at month/date/week...grab data for that period and show it. When he goes back one year, he will have all the data still available.

Answer (score -2):

Have you met my friend, [Google](http://google.com/?q=asp.net%20open%20source%20event%20calendar)?

In particular, [4GuysFromRolla has a tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20211029043748/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/041603-1.aspx), and there is a [nice looking open source calendar control](http://www.daypilot.org/daypilot-lite.html) with [some tutorials](http://www.daypilot.org/tutorials.html) that should get you well on your way.

Comment: I didn't think links (or suggestions to google) could be considered answers... with all due respect, shouldn't this be a comment?

Comment: @M.Babcock - Suggestions to Google should be a comment - but I don't see how links to specific tutorials isn't a valid answer to the vague "question" the OP asked. I'll admit to the snarkiness - but it still seems infinitely more helpful to the OP than going back-and-forth in comments.

Comment: If the question is vague then it should be voted as such, and my comment on the question was to suggest to the OP where he may be able to go to get more help (because this question is not appropriate for SO). My comment to you was merely a suggestion based on being previously beat up for doing something similar. Under any circumstance, I don't agree that this answer should have been downvoted...